# Using <keygen> to get an RSA key for use with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, rsa

I need an RSA key pair for my web project and while there are some libraries I think it would be a good idea to rely on the browser (for security and speed) to generate the key for me. Is it possible to use keygen or something an other browser API to do so? I don't know how to get the keys from keygen. They seem to be generated on submit, but I don't want to send them to the server.

Comment: They're not sent to the server.

Comment: According to the specification the public key will be sent.

Comment: @nep: Yes, that's the point - only the public key will be sent (to identify the user in future sessions) but the private key is stored in the browser where the server (and server's JavaScript) can never access it. So nobody can fake user's identity, not even the server itself.

Comment: I found this article that is well worth a read :  http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is something like Mozilla's [DOMCrypt API proposal](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Privacy/Features/DOMCryptAPISpec/Latest). It allows you to generate a key pair via `window.mozCrypto.pk.generateKeypair()` (`window.mozCrypto` is supposed to change into `window.crypto` later), you can get the public key and also encrypt or decrypt text with the private key. It will still not grant you direct access to the private key however, you only get a key ID.

Unfortunately, this API isn't supported by any browser yet. There is only a [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/domcrypt/) that can be used to test it, so that proposal is still in a very early stage. But I think that's the best you can get at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [site](http://ats.oka.nu/titaniumcore/js/crypto/RSA.sample1.html), talking about generating RSA keys within the browser

Comment: I think it was down-voted because it doesn't really answer the question - the question was about using the browser's built-in capabilities as opposed to third-party libraries.

Comment: yeah, I just went to it expecting an answer, but I got an example instead, which I would need to dig through; and maybe I'll get an answer.

Comment: The question was down voted because according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer you should "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link."

Answer (score 0):

There is a SSL-like protocol implemented in JavaScript : [aSSL](http://assl.sullof.com/assl/).

It uses a RSA algorithm for cryptography you could use their Keys generator.

Answer (score -1):

Let's just say this is a scary idea due to the possibility of injecting code that steals the private key.