# Private key of keygen tag

Tags: java, security, html

The key-pair generator generates two keys, one private and one public. The private key is stored on the client, and the public key is sent to the server. The private key generated by the `<keygen>` tag is automatically stored by the browser. How can I retrieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure how that protocol works, but since it's a private key, hopefully you CANNOT retrieve it!

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I am assuming that the program is on the browser side (client side) to access the private key. If so then I am sure it is possible, other wise it is not possible unless you go through unsanctioned means.

Comment: Are you using an applet for this? (html5 + java)

Comment: I am using html+jsp,@Zeveso:Yes,I want to access private key on the browser side(client side).How can it be possible??

Comment: Please reply to my question..

Comment: The whole point of the keygen tag is that the private key can't be retrieved by javascript running in the context of a website.

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know if that is good idea. `keygen` is not supported in IE (IE always messes things up) and there are people who still use IE. However, if you need an encryption key, I found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7200829/1212968). There are a couple of good answers there.